# Why is Emacs complaining about risky file-local variables?

Tags: security, variables, emacs, purescript

Trying to use `purescript-mode` with GNU Emacs 24.5.1, whenever I return a newline in a purescript file, Emacs opens a new window to tell me:

```
purescript-mode-hook is a variable defined in `purescript-mode.el'.
Its value is (capitalized-words-mode)
Original value was nil

This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
```

After a bit of research, I added the following to my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values 
  '(purescript-mode-hook . capitalized-words-mode))
```

Now, when I return a newline in a purescript file, Emacs still opens a new window to tell me:

```
purescript-mode-hook is a variable defined in `purescript-mode.el'.
Its value is (capitalized-words-mode)
Original value was nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
  However, you have added it to `safe-local-variable-values'.
```

If I've explicitly told Emacs that it's safe, why is it still complaining? How can I suppress this behavior?

Comment: Consider making an Emacs enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I thought it might be, but I wanted to get some input before calling it a bug -- maybe I'm missing something about the expected behavior here...

Comment: Did you add that `safe-local-variable-values` manually?  I'd guess the value is `(capitalized-words-mode)` rather than `capitalized-words-mode`; IOW it's a list of function symbols not a single function symbol.  But beyond that, it seems like maybe a bug in purescript-mode, which is not part of Emacs.  I'd report the bug to the purescript-mode project.

Answer (score 0):

I am fighting the same dragon... `purescript-mode-hook` is considered risky because `risky-local-variable-p` is returning non-nil.

> risky-local-variable-p is a byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘files.el’.
>
> (risky-local-variable-p SYM &optional IGNORED)
>
> Non-nil if SYM could be dangerous as a file-local variable.
> It is dangerous if either of these conditions are met:
>
> - Its ‘risky-local-variable’ property is non-nil.
> - Its name ends with "hook(s)", "function(s)", "form(s)", "map",
>   "program", "command(s)", "predicate(s)", "frame-alist",
>   "mode-alist", "font-lock-(syntactic-)keyword*",
>   "map-alist", or "bindat-spec".
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 22.1.

It appears for *risky* variables, the only choice you have is to set `enable-local-variables` to `:all`.  **BUT**:

> enable-local-variables is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
>
> Its value is t
>
> Control use of local variables in files you visit.
> The value can be t, nil, :safe, :all, or something else.
>
> A value of t means file local variables specifications are obeyed
> if all the specified variable values are safe; if any values are
> not safe, Emacs queries you, once, whether to set them all.
> (When you say yes to certain values, they are remembered as safe.)
>
> :safe means set the safe variables, and ignore the rest.
> :all means set all variables, whether safe or not.
> **(Don’t set it permanently to :all.)**
> A value of nil means always ignore the file local variables.
>
> Any other value means always query you once whether to set them all.
> (When you say yes to certain values, they are remembered as safe, but
> this has no effect when ‘enable-local-variables’ is "something else".)
>
> This variable also controls use of major modes specified in
> a -*- line.
>
> The command M-x normal-mode, when used interactively,
> always obeys file local variable specifications and the -*- line,
> and ignores this variable.
>
> Also see the ‘permanently-enabled-local-variables’ variable.
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
> You can customize this variable.
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.20.